# Riemann sum of improper integral over real line

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

On a physics problem sheet I had to use the following identity:
$$\lim_{a\downarrow0}\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}af(ja) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx,$$
where $f: \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$. Under what conditions on $f$ does this hold? This looks like a Riemann sum where instead of a compact interval the whole real line is partitioned into intervals of length $a$. I've tried to play a little bit around with the definition of the improper integral as the limit of finite integrals but I am stuck. I suppose that $\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$ means $\lim_{z \to \infty} \sum_{j=-z}^z,$ so the improper integral should be read as taking the Cauchy principal value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The improper integral cannot always be obtained as a limit of Riemann or Riemann-like sums.  This is basically a question of whether or not iterated double limits exist and/or are equal. It depends on the nature of $f$.  If $f$ is monotone then it usually works out as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2129782/148510).

As a counterexample, take a function $f$ where $f(k) = 1$ at any integer $k$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. Here we have 
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx = 0$$

However, for the sequence $a_n = 2^{-n},$

$$\lim_{a_n \to 0+} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_nf(ja_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{j=1}^{m2^n} f(j/2^n)  = +\infty$$

Comment: What about exchanging the limits to $\lim_{m\to \infty} \lim_{a \downarrow 0} \sum_{j=0}^m af(aj$? Here it would work for this counterexample. Are there other examples where it doesn't work?

Comment: @JannikPitt: Of course, my counterexample just illustrates a case where equality of a convergent improper integral and the limit of the "Rieman" sum fails simply because the sum is divergent.  Perhaps you want to see an example where both sides are convergent but unequal.

Comment: Yes, such an example would be nice. Also a continuous counterexample would be interesting.

Comment: @JannikPitt:  If $f$ is monotone, then as long as the series is convergent what you wrote is correct.  For example $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + (k/n)^2} = \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$.  However there is a double limiting process here and if we are careless about the order we see, for example, $\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{1 + (k/n)^2} = 0$ or $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + (k/n)^2} =  \int_0^1\frac{dx}{1 + x^2} =\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: My examples involve integrals over $[0,\infty)$ for simplicity.  When the interval is $(-\infty,\infty)$ you should consider splitting into contributions over $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0, \infty)$ to apply the monotone argument.