# Error of approximating infinite series by integral

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, approximation

I need to evaluate a sum
$\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty f\left(\frac{m}{L}\right)$
and tried to approximate it by an integral for $L\rightarrow\infty$
$\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty f\left(\frac{m}{L}\right)\approx L\int\limits_0^\infty f(x) dx$
where I will be left with some error $\propto L^{-\alpha}$ for some $\alpha >0$. Everything is finite and converges nicely, however the approximation I made seems too course for my needs, so I was wondering:

Is there a better approximation to improve the convergence, or are there error terms to some order that are worth including?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Approximation_of_integrals

Comment: Thanks, I am still a little confused since I can‘t see the dependence on subdivisions in this article. Is this (to first order) equivalent to the typical Riemann Integral procedure?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129293/transition-from-a-riemann-sum-to-an-integral?noredirect=1